# python scrapy does not working - "ImportError: No module named settings"

Tags: python, scrapy

scrappy lib in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy`
my project catalog:

```
.../projects/scrapy                                       
.../projects/parser_module                                     
....../projects/parser_module/parser  
....../projects/parser_module/parser           
........../projects/parser_module/parser/spiders/.....     
........../projects/parser_module/parser/<files etc>   
....../projects/parser_module/scrapy.cfg
```

In directory `.../projects/parser_module/` I am set command `scrapy crawl parser` and get result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                   

 File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>                                                         
   execute()                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 109, in execute  
  settings = get_project_settings() 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings  
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')          
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 108, in setmodule        
    module = import_module(module)                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module                       
    __import__(name)                                                                                 
ImportError: No module named settings
```

Can you please tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

to avoid such issue create your project folder with `scrapy startproject parser_module`

now to fix your issue, you either have a fresh start or create a dummy project with `scrapy startproject` to copy setting.py from. Then maybe next error you will find other missing file in this folder.

This is the typical structure of a scrapy project.

```
.
├── scrapy.cfg
└── project_name
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        └── __init__.py
            spider.py
```

Comment: @taifun, You mean fixing the people is not a better solution than fixing the code ?

Comment: thanks @Frederic Bazin. I now understand that one need to  create scrapy project with proper use of command. Otherwise chances are you may find yourself in trouble, specially, problems related to project configuration

Comment: Unfortunately in the documentation making project via `startproject` command still not mentioned as the first thing to do. That's why new users are in trouble, as "First glance" and "installation guide" doesn't mention `startproject` command. It's mentioned only in "Command line tool" at Basic Concepts. Sure, it's my fault that I haven't looked there before, but still it should be mentioned in the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

To solve "ImportError: No module named *.settings", try to change project name and related settings in `scrapy.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved by removing the **init.pyc** file which was present just inside the scrapy project directory

Answer (score -1):

I found myself problem, next is solve:

My project name is: `superproject`

I recieved problem **"ImportError: No module named project"**

In my `settings.py` was row `ROTATING_PROXY_BAN_POLICY = 'project.policy.BanPolicy'`.

Warning! Projects name is different. In `settings.py` yours names must be like `superproject` and dependency.

If rename `ROTATING_PROXY_BAN_POLICY = 'project.policy.BanPolicy'` TO => `ROTATING_PROXY_BAN_POLICY = 'superproject.policy.BanPolicy'`, THEN prolem was solving.